# ShowWindow/HideWindow in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, macos, appkit

In Carbon you could change a window's visibility with HideWindow(WindowRef) and ShowWindow(WindowRef).

In Cocoa I know you can call NSWindow's orderOut: to hide and orderFront:, orderBack: or orderWindow:relativeTo: to put it back on screen, but none of those respect the ordering of the window relative to other windows when it was last visible.

For example, if I have two windows, one above the other, and then call orderOut: on the back window, how do I show the window again such that it is still behind the front window **without calling orderWindow:relativeTo:**.

The only thing I can think of right now is to remember the window ID of the window immediately above it and then use orderWindow:relativeTo: when showing it again, but I haven't thought through what happens if the window above is closed before the rear window is made visible again.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, because of the difference in how Carbon thought and Cocoa thinks about window visibility. In Carbon, there was a window-is-visible Boolean flag, separate from its order among the application's windows. In Cocoa (at least in the API), there is only the order; a window that is visible is in the order (ordered in), while a window that is not visible is not in the order (ordered out). As such, “hiding” (ordering out) a window in Cocoa destroys any information about where it was in the order. So, yes, I think you will need to preserve that information yourself.

Comment: @Peter, your comment matches up pretty well with what I've found so far. I no longer work on the project where I had this problem, so hopefully someone else will benefit from the question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any method available in Cocoa. I guess you need to mimic that using your idea.

By the way, what was the Carbon behavior if you start from four windows ordered as

```
 A B X C D E
```

Then hide `X`

```
 A B C D E
```

Now the user reorders them, and removes some:

```
 E A C
```

and then show `X` again. Where did `X` go in Carbon in this case?

Comment: The documentation says “`ShowWindow` does not change the front-to-back ordering of windows”. Assuming the user achieved that order by bringing A and then C to the front (leaving E now the backmost visible window), X, which was behind E, should now be the backmost window.